# WHERE ID = MAX(ID) Getting Error Aggregate May Not Appear

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having a problem with a query I have put together, I have followed the explanation on http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-147.aspx (bottom of the page) and I can't see much difference in my code to the example other than an addition to the WHERE clause and an Inner Join.

Yet I am still getting the following error:

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

This is my own code:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [dbo].[mail] AS rm
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[mytbl] AS ec ON [rm].[webref] = [ec].[Webref]
WHERE   rm.[webref] = 'XYZ-594112'
    AND [PolRef@] = ( SELECT    MAX([PolRef@])
                      FROM      [dbo].[mytbl]
                    )
```

Can anyone shed any light as to why this is occurring?

EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mail](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[date] [datetime] NULL,
[webref] [nvarchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The other table is actually a view that is comprised of several other tables, however the a cut down version would be:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytbl](
[PolRef@] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Webref] [varchar](30) NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
```

EDIT UPDATE:

Now getting the following error:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [FreshSystems].[dbo].[mail] AS rm
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[mytbl] AS ec ON [rm].[webref] = [ec].[Webref]
WHERE   rm.[webref] = 'XYZ-594112'
HAVING [PolRef@] = ( SELECT    MAX([PolRef@])
                      FROM      [dbo].[mytbl]
                    )
```

Error

```
Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Column 'mytbl.PolRef@' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not     contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

WORKING:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [dbo].[mail] AS rm
LEFT OUTER JOIN  [dbo].[mytbl] AS ec ON [rm].[webref] = [ec].[Webref]
WHERE   rm.[webref] = 'XYZ-594112'
AND [PolRef@] = ( SELECT    MAX([PolRef@])
                  FROM      [dbo].[mytbl]
                  WHERE [Webref] = 'XYZ-594112'
                )
```

Comment: This looks like a valid SQL query, strange.

Comment: Could we see DDL for the two tables involved please? Can't repro with the first tables that came to hand...

Comment: I can't reproduce too...

Comment: @AakashM Forgive me I'm not a SQL Guru I am just trying my best - by DDL I take it you mean the CREATE statements for the 2 tables involved? Apologies.

Comment: Yes, sorry, DDL = Data Definition Language, the `CREATE TABLE`s and so on (The 'opposite' term is DML = Data Manipulation Language, `SELECT` `UPDATE` etc)

Comment: Which table is `PolRef@` a column of?

Comment: @AakashM - Good Call :).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - PolRef@ is part of mytbl.

Comment: @Lynchie, you've just changed `[mail]` to `[mytbl]` in your subquery. Are you showing us the real, original query or some slightly modified version?

Comment: And does it work now that you've changed the table in the subquery?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I rectified your point and have updated with further code.

Comment: That first query runs fine for me.  And That last error message is pretty clear - cannot have a "having" without a "group by".

Comment: Finally got it. After a bit of mucking around! Thanks everyone involved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WORKING CODE:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [dbo].[mail] AS rm
LEFT OUTER JOIN  [dbo].[mytbl] AS ec ON [rm].[webref] = [ec].[Webref]
WHERE   rm.[webref] = 'XYZ-594112'
AND [PolRef@] = ( SELECT    MAX([PolRef@])
                  FROM      [dbo].[mytbl]
                  WHERE [Webref] = 'XYZ-594112'
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this

```
select  *
from    [dbo].[mail] as rm
join    [dbo].[mytbl] as ec
on      [rm].[webref] = [ec].[webref]
join    ( select    max([polref@]) y
          from      [dbo].[mail]
        ) x
on      [polref@] = x.y
where   rm.[webref] = 'xyz-594112'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just order by `poltef@ desc` and take the top 1:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * WITH TIES
FROM mail rm
JOIN mytbl ec ON rm.webref = ec.Webref
WHERE rm.webref = 'XYZ-594112'
ORDER BY poltef@ desc
```

Also, I have removed all unnecessary characters.

Comment: This is not the same semantics as the original query. It would be closer with `WITH TIES` but still not the same. Also [omitting schema is not an improvement](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)

Comment: @MartinSmith I did think about ties for max but ignored ot be ause I've never used with ties before (not a MS fan) but I recall seeing it -  just didn't realise how simple the syntax was, so I'm glad you prompted me to use it. As for the schema and general square bracket fest, disagree completely: It's clutter IMHO and if you share a server with another schema "one day", I say worry about it *if* it happens (although I have tempered my comment to remove opinion from fact)